# 'No timewasters!' and 'Serious inquiries only' - Slogans in job adverts. Do they achieve anything?

Tags: job-offer

Thankfully I am retired and don't have to worry about this any more.

When googling on a different subject I came across the following

> Animal Vacancies - 14 urgent openings. No timewasters!

The link is no longer operative but it is a very common phrase used in small-ads.

Why do employers use this phrase? 
Do timewasters know that they are timewasters?  Or, if they are deliberate timewasters surely they will not be deterred.

Has anyone here ever used that phrase? Did it achieve anything?

---

**Update: 18 Sep 2015** - in response to the following comment

> It sounds like an impolite version of "serious inquiries only" –  Dan Pichelman

I'd like to ask about this as well. Does this 'polite' version achieve anything useful?  Does the phrase stop frivolous or unsuitable applications?

Comment: It's a lousy ad no matter how you slice it; "animal vacancies" is supremely uninformative, and is going to draw lots of inquiries from the wrong people, I.e. "timewasters". Don't compound the problem, fix it.

Comment: I have never seen that phrase in an ad, but I know I would not apply if I saw it because it indicates the company is very unprofessional and that will carry over to pay and benefits and how you are treated on a day-to-day basis.This basically says my employees are going to be treated like furniture.

Comment: "no timewasters!" is a common phrase in job ads?

Comment: And you really don't want to spend too much time thinking about animals with 14 vacant openings... though I suppose that might indeed save time if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: I've just been checking and it seems even more common on adverts selling cars! Perhaps I should find some examples where the links still work. I'll come back later.

Comment: Or maybe they're vacancies that need to be filled with/by animals. Then you have to decide whether this usage of "animal" excludes humans; Shakespeare would say it doesn't. ("The paragon of animals" -- Hamlet)

Comment: It sounds like an impolite version of "serious inquiries only"

Comment: Well, it saves one word, which may reduce the ad's cost... but it's still a bad ad, with or without the offending phrase; pinching pennies on that word makes the business owner look like even more of a cheapskate. Not an ad I'd ever want to respond to.

Comment: @DanPichelman - I've added that to my question because I'm  not sure what the polite version is supposed to achieve either.

Comment: I'll be honest- I usually apply to anything that says "no timewasters" for the irony.

Comment: My guess would be...no.  No point.

Comment: My guess is its intended to make potential applicants think "This company doesn't like timewasters, and I don't like timewasters, so we must be a good fit".

Comment: I don't know if it works but as for why they do it, I am reminded of this letter from a hiring manager who frequently had applicants get scheduled for an interview and then neither show up nor call: http://www.askamanager.org/2013/04/when-candidates-no-call-no-show-for-an-interview-and-then-reapply.html

Comment: Just imagine the reverse situation - you send your cover letter to a prospective employer and include such a "warning" phrase as "Serious job offer possibilities only!" or something like that. I wouldn't be suprised if that inclusion has the opposite effect and you simply don't get called back.

Comment: @Brandin Putting your salary target in the cover letter is a good "warning phrase."  Some employers who can't afford you will take it seriously and not call you back.  If the salary target is realistic, then that is a "Good Thing" (TM).

Comment: I've voted to close this as it's purely opinion based and answers are likely to devolve into discussions instead.

Answer (score 10):

I can't imagine that it would achieve anything.  After all, who goes to a job interview with the idea that they are completely unsuitable but they just were bored and they want to mess with you?  (unless you are @Studoko, in which case the phrase would be counterproductive :)

Most timewasters happen when people are not good at self evaluation, and those people wouldn't even realize the phrase applied to *them*.

Or when the job requirements are not clearly enough defined.  Far better to be more specific on what factors would cause them to *be* timewasters (like "no red heads" "no bald guys" "no people who can't read", etc)  If you haven't got the space to actually *explain* what you want, resign time to being wasted (yours and theirs).

Comment: spot on, I've seen plenty show up to interviews totally unsuitable, unprepared and unqualified for the position, I doubt they'd be deterred by that statement on an ad.

Comment: UI says you have to apply to 2 jobs per week.  In the past, I have applied for a position as a surgeon even though I have no medical degree.  It would be concerning if I had been invited in for an interview, but if I had and declined then UI would have a reason to cut me off.

Comment: Here's the way I see it.  If I get a job offer from a job that I don't want (I never have but I suppose it could happen) and I was worried about that UI rule (and yes, I have been) I would be upfront with the folks making me the offer and tell them I would not be a good fit.  If they *insist* on offering me the job and even go so far as threatening to tattle to unemployment, that just means you will just be getting paid while you continue your job search.  It's a feature, not a bug :)

Answer (score 7):

I suspect these phrases are a kind of trick, a bit like "limited time offers" that seem to have been available for years. By suggesting that they are expecting to be flooded with responses from people who aren't prepared to take the process seriously or put in the effort required to land the job, they make the job sound more alluring. Oooh, you are supposed to think, what is this mysterious animal vacancy that is hard to land and that everyone will want to vaguely try for in a non serious timewasting way? Maybe I want it too!

There's a good chance that there is in fact no job, just an application process that somehow makes money for the placer of the small ad. You might need to pay some sort of application fee, or get photos taken that the ad-placer can co-ordinate for $100 or so, or work a free day doing deliveries or other odd jobs as a test, and these are the things that the ad is actually trying to solicit. People who balk at them will be called time wasters or reminded that only serious enquiries were requested.

Your smart move is to snort with laughter and move on.

Comment: That's a plausible and worrying answer. A friend's daughter studied for several years, got a degree, took up unpaid work at an animal sanctuary
 and after doing that for a year and getting good references was unable to get a job in the field. She has now given up her ambition and works (successfully it must be said) in supermarket management. She tells me there are long waiting lists, especially of young women in their early twenties, who would like to work with animals. Presumably a scam such as the one you describe would be designed specifically to appeal to this market.

Answer (score 4):

Both "no timewasters" and "serious inquiries only" essentially say

> If you contact me, I'm gonna assume your not worth my time unless you
>   prove it.

If you're a scammer, this is the type of person you can fleece. Most people have gotten wise to job scams, so if you write up a professional looking job posting, you're likely to get professionals applying.  A professional is going to hang up the moment they have to pay a $100 application fee or some other non-sense.  The scammer doesn't want professionals who have heard of this one before, he needs naive and desperate people who don't have the experience to know not to pay to get hired.

The scammer could make his application look really unprofessional, but that would cause problems when he tries to sell the business as legitimate to his marks.  So the scammer takes the stance of every caller must prove (by paying an application fee or buying a do-hicky) they are worth the scammers time.

NOTE: I'm focusing on the scam angle due to the number of times I've seen these words following "Secret Shopper" jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for "serious inquiries only" is a waste of time. I helped with the hiring process at my previous job. We regularly received resumes along the lines of "I've been a salesman all my life, but I've always wanted to be a rocket scientist." (My employer was a company of rocket scientists.)

A couple of people had to waste their time filtering out those non-serious inquiries. Asking for serious inquiries didn't help; those salesmen who had always wanted to be rocket scientists were quite serious in their minds when they asked us to give them a job. Every once in a while those filterers would send the best of the best (or worst of the worst) such applications around, for laughs.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I believe anything along the lines of "serious inquiries only" applies is for sale of high end items.

For example, a Ferrari salesman would certainly not want to deal with people who not only couldn't afford to buy the car but honestly wouldn't even try.  You know, those people that just wanted to sit in a Ferrari because they thought that would be a fun way to spend a few hours on a Saturday.

In regards to job hunting, I don't see that it has a useful place.  The statement attempts to say "we're serious about hiring people right now so you should be too!" in order to underscore the previous adjective of "urgent".

On the other hand filling low (or no) skilled jobs is often a difficult task.  People schedule interviews, then no show.  People show up to the interviews, are offered a job, then no show.  Sometimes they even make it to the first week and simply stop coming in.  At some point a hiring manager might feel the need to say "listen, if you aren't serious about a job please move along" - unfortunately, it's just the nature of the business of hiring people.

Comment: Yes. Clearly these managers have experienced time-wasters in the past and want to avoid them in the future. Part of my question was to see if anyone would admit to using these expressions and, perhaps more importantly:- "If you did use something like this, did it actually reduce the numbers of time-wasters?"  If the technique actually works then maybe it's a useful strategy after all.